# What is wrong with this ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

Why does it not print "Hello" in my browser?

I have this code in a file called `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning Ajax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Learning Ajax</h1>
        <a href="files/ajax.txt">Load Ajax Text File</a>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and also this code in a file called `main.js`

```
var message = "Hello";

$(function() {
    var message = "Goodbye";
})();

alert(message);
```

its a self invoking anonymous function

Comment: There is no AJAX code being used here.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?  You should really be looking at your console when developing HTML/JavaScript.  Also, you are using `$`, but you don't have jQuery loaded (`$(function(){})()` is incorrect anyway, the `()` at the end are wrong).

Comment: You should first learn JavaScript then you'll understand what is Ajax and how this works!

Answer (score 2):

Because of error: you use `$`, but there is no such function you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

There's no AJAX in the code above. I recommend visiting jQuery's learning website and finding out what AJAX is all about and how it works: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.